# Refactoring the data type of a variable which is used across multiple modules of an application

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, refactoring

I want to refactor datatype of a variable from Float to Double.
The variable is used across multiple module of an application. It is very difficult and time consuming to find and refactor the datatype across the application. 
Is there an easier way to do this. I am using Eclipse Indigo IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Would a simple find and replace on "float myVariable" (replace with "double myVariable")  not find most instances where you're initializing the variable, assuming it carries the same name throughout the app?  You might have to still find any cases where you're doing anything float specific (casting is the only thing that immediately jumps to mind) but that should change the datatype across the majority of your application.  Let me know if I've misunderstood something.

Comment: It is can be a return value for a method. so the return type of the method also needs to be changed. I have around 100 classes where this kind of refactoring needs to be done.

Secondly it is used for some calculations so even that needs to be taken under consideration.

Comment: Ahhh, there's the complexity.  Sorry, that's a little out of my depth; I don't know enough about Eclipse.